# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function insert() on null in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, database, wordpress

I am inserting the data into the database in WordPress. I am getting an error in the network tab:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function insert() on null

This is my logic

```
<?php
  global $wpdb;        // <--- making $wpdb as global
  $wpdb->insert('contact',
    array(
      'name' => $_POST['c_name'],
      'email' => $_POST['c_email'],
      'phone' => $_POST['c_mobileno'],
      'type_of_services' => $_POST['c_type_of_services'],
      'message' => $_POST['c_message']
    ),
    array(
      '%s',
      '%s',
      '%s',
      '%s',
      '%s',
    )
  );
  // $wpdb->show_errors(); 
?>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#contact_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: "/process.php",
      type: "post",
      data: form.serialize(),           
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(response) {
        alert("submited");
      }
    });
  });     
});
```

Comment: I'm no PHP expert, but the error would imply that `$wpdb` is null. Have you attempted to debug why that may be?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes you are right

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, $wpdb is null but how can I check that? I am getting my post data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope help you. Add in your php file:

```
define( 'BLOCK_LOAD', true );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php' );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php' );
$wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
```

Comment: You mean to say I have to add this answer on process.php?

Comment: @NarenVerma Yes

Comment: Yes it's working. I thought this is inbuild in WordPress.

Comment: I will accept this and upvote you soon. I need two more help with this. 1) should I need to use some SQL injection? 2) I think I have to use json_encode to display the alert.

Comment: 1.) https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25947/wpdb-insert-do-i-need-to-prepare-against-sql-injection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203180/discussion-between-dmitry-and-naren-verma).

Comment: worked very well, Thanks!